Getting a 400 error when exchanging authorization code for access token in Spotify API integration
I'm working on integrating Spotify API into my web application using the Authorization Code with PKCE Flow. I've followed the documentation provided by Spotify, but I'm encountering a 400 error when trying to exchange the authorization code for an access token.
Here's a summary of what I've done:

Implemented the PKCE extension to generate a code verifier and code challenge.
Redirected the user to Spotify's authorization page with the appropriate parameters, including the code challenge.
After the user grants permission, received the authorization code in the callback URL.
Attempted to exchange the authorization code for an access token using a POST request to Spotify's token endpoint.

However, the POST request to exchange the authorization code for an access token is failing with a 400 error. I've double-checked the parameters, including client_id, grant_type, redirect_uri, code_verifier, and code, and they all seem to be correct.
Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:
const clientId = [YOUR_CLIENT_ID];
const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000';

const generateAuthCode = async () => {
  // Generate code verifier
  const codeVerifier = 'generated_code_verifier';

  // Redirect user to Spotify authorization page
  const authUrl = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';
  const params = {
    response_type: 'code',
    client_id: clientId,
    scope: 'playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private',
    code_challenge_method: 'S256',
    code_challenge: 'generated_code_challenge',
    redirect_uri: redirectUri,
  };
  const queryString = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();
  window.location.href = `${authUrl}?${queryString}`;
};

const generateAccessToken = async (code, setUserInfo) => {
  // Exchange authorization code for access token
  const url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';
  const payload = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      client_id: clientId,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code,
      redirect_uri: redirectUri,
      code_verifier: 'stored_code_verifier',
    }),
  };

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, payload);
    const responseData = await response.json();
    setUserInfo((prevInfo) => ({
      api_key: responseData.access_token,
      userId: prevInfo.userId,
    }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error:', error);
  }
};

export { generateAuthCode, generateAccessToken };


I've also logged the response from the server, but it doesn't provide much information beyond the 400 status code and a message stating "invalid authorization code". I believe this is due to an expired authorization code but I'm not sure how to go about fixing this issue.
Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I believe this is due to an expired authorization code but I'm not sure how to go about fixing this issue. have you considered using a non-expired authorization code?

@JaromandaX Yes but the authorization code is is programmatically generated within the JS code, so I am uncertain as to why it is expiring when a new code should be generated each time the application launches. Despite following the documentation closely, I have not found a solution. I would greatly appreciate guidance on how to modify my code to resolve this issue. I apologize if this seems like a basic question; I am still relatively new to this process.

I had the same issue and I figured out the authorization code expires right after being used and becomes obsolete after one use only. The flow is working well just after the autorization prompt, but not upon reload.
So my workaround is to store the info "post_authorization".

If True, we generate a token based on the "code" we get from window.location
If False, either we already have an access_token and we can go to the next step, either we don't and we need another authorization



const appClientId = "your client id";
const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:5173/callback'; 

const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
var postAuthorization = localStorage.getItem("post_authorization")
console.log("postAuthorization: " + postAuthorization)
console.log("accessToken: " + accessToken)

if ((!accessToken || accessToken === 'undefined') && (!postAuthorization || postAuthorization === 'no')) {
    console.log("Auth flow");
    localStorage.setItem('post_authorization', 'yes')
    redirectToAuthCodeFlow(appClientId);
} else if (postAuthorization === 'yes') {
    console.log("Post Auth flow");
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const userCode = params.get("code");
    const accessToken = await getAccessToken(appClientId, userCode);
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', accessToken); // Store the access token
    console.log("accessToken is saved to "+accessToken)
    let postAuthorization = 'no';
    localStorage.setItem('post_authorization', "no"); // Can now connect directly with the access token
    const profile = await fetchProfile(accessToken);
    populateUI(profile);
} else {
    console.log("Post Access Token");
    const profile = await fetchProfile(accessToken);
    populateUI(profile);
}



